# Leer directorio desde consola en C

Tags: c

Hola tengo el siguiente código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <dirent.h> // Libreria encargada del tema de los directorios
#include <string.h>

void load(){
    char dir[250];
    DIR *carpeta;
    struct dirent *archivo;

    CLEAR
    printf("Arrastre la carpeta a la ventana o ingrese la direccion para indexar\n");
    fgets(dir,250,stdin);

    carpeta = opendir(dir);

    if (carpeta != NULL){
        while ((archivo = readdir(carpeta))) puts (archivo->d_name);
        closedir(carpeta);
    }else
        perror ("Error al abrir el directorio ");

    getchar();
}
```

Dado una dirección de una carpeta, lista los archivos que se encuentran dentro de la misma, el problema es que simplemente no lee los archivos cuando los arrastro a la consola, pero si lo hace cuando escribo la dirección directamente en el archivo `.c`

Aqui arrastre la carpeta a la ventana:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui realice un cambio en el código e introduje directamente la misma dirección de la carpeta que arrastre

```
carpeta = opendir("/Users/cristoferfb/Documents/Universidad");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver en la segunda ocasión realiza su tarea sin ningún problema.

Cabe destacar que al ingresar carpetas con espacios en los nombres se generan símbolos extraños:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esos `\` no son parte del nombre y los eh tratado de quitar pero al final tampoco funciona.

**pd:** estoy trabajando bajo **macOs** Sierra con gcc

Comment: No son simbolos extraños, cuando hay un espacio en blanco se le añade una barra descendente para que se interpreten como un bloque. De lo contrario corres el riesgo de que el nombre del directorio o fichero se corte con el primer espacio en blanco (p.e. `/Users/cristoferfb/Documents/Universidad/Estructura de datos` se interpretaría como 3 parámetros: `/Users/cristoferfb/Documents/Universidad/Estructura`, `de` y `datos` , pero al poner el \ delante de los espacios, se interpreta como uno solo: `/Users/cristoferfb/Documents/Universidad/Estructura\ de\ datos`)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro gracias por la aclaración de ese aspecto.

Comment: ¿Has probado a mostrar por consola el valor de `dir`?¿Qué valor tiene? Podría ser un problema de escape de caracteres (quizás haya que añadir \ delante de los / para que se procese correctamente el nombre)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro al imprimir dir se me imprime exactamente igual que como se ingresa tratare de usar \ pero no veo por qué si los / jamás han necesitado secuencia de escape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para el primer ejemplo basado en sus imagenes -> `"/Users/cristoferfb/Documents/Universidad"` hice una prueba similar y no le funciona porque `fgets()` lee/captura el `newline` por ejemplo intente lo siguiente:

```
if(isspace(dir[strlen(dir)-1]))
          dir[strlen(dir)-1]='\0';
```

.

```
    char dir[250];
    DIR *carpeta;
    struct dirent *archivo;

    //CLEAR
    printf("Arrastre la carpeta a la ventana o ingrese la direccion para indexar\n");
    fgets(dir,250,stdin);

    if(isspace(dir[strlen(dir)-1]))
                dir[strlen(dir)-1]='\0';

    carpeta = opendir(dir);

    if (carpeta != NULL){
        while ((archivo = readdir(carpeta))) puts (archivo->d_name);
        closedir(carpeta);
    }else
        perror ("Error al abrir el directorio ");

    getchar();
```

Yo no puedo probar con lo de soltar los directorios en la terminal pues la que yo uso no acepta eso, pero el sistema que emplea es muy similar y funciono para una ruta asi.

`/ruta/a/sin/espacios_ni_descendente`

si no le funciona para ese estilo de rutas igual tiene que limpiar los `\` antes de pasarlos al `opendir` mirar si contenido de `dir` despues del uso de `if(isspace...` tiene esos caracteres y remplazarlos. pero como digo esta parte no la puedo mirar, aun el primer error es por lo que se comenta del `fgets`.

Con `\` me refiero a `/Users/cristoferfb/Documents/Universidad/Estructura\ de\ datos`

---

> UPDATE:

He realizado alguna pruebas y con una ruta como esta `/Users/cristoferfb/Documents/Universidad/Estructura de datos` o como esta otra `/Users/cristoferfb/Documents/Universidad/Estructura de datos.` deberia de funcionar, lo que quiero decir es que al asinar a `dir` y despues de apliar el `if(isspace...` aplique una funcion que elimine las \ backslash, pero que deje el espacio siguiente como se muesta mas arriba. esto creo deberia de bastar pero si no es asi trate de añadir un `.` al final

---

Le dejo un ejemplo (tomese como pseudocode) pues esta realizado para ilustrar y aunque funciona se puede mejorar.

```
    char dir[250];
    DIR *carpeta;
    struct dirent *archivo;

    //CLEAR
    printf("Arrastre la carpeta a la ventana o ingrese la direccion para indexar\n");

    fgets(dir,250,stdin);

    if(isspace(dir[strlen(dir)-1]))
                dir[strlen(dir)-1]='\0';

    int j = 0;

     while (dir[j] != '\0'){

        if (dir[j] == '\\' ) {

           int idx = j; 

           memmove(&dir[idx], &dir[idx + 1], strlen(dir) - idx);

        }
        j++;
    }

    carpeta = opendir(dir);

    if (carpeta != NULL){
        while ((archivo = readdir(carpeta))) puts (archivo->d_name);
        closedir(carpeta);
    }else
        perror ("Error al abrir el directorio ");

    getchar();
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta como comentas habían problemas más que nada con un espacio en blanco que había al final de la cadena, lo repare con una función trim y ya está pero claro sigo teniendo el problema de los archivos con espacios en el nombre

Comment: @CristoferFuentes P.D: no lo se pero la funcion `trim` esa que comenta no estara borrando los espacios tambien en esta parte -> `/Estructura\ de\ datos` dejando algo asi `/Estructura\de\datos` lo cual igual no es valido como ruta. Intente el codigo que le deje yo para ese tipo de rutas, igual le funciona sin usar el `trim` que comenta Saludos

Comment: @CristoferFuentes tambien puede intentar el suprimir los \ dejando la ruta donde aparezcan asi `/Users/cristoferfb/Documents/Universidad/Estructura de datos` o asi `/Users/cristoferfb/Documents/Universidad/Estructura de datos.` fijese el punto del final, se lo comento porque yo no puedo probarlo. Saludos

Comment: @CristoferFuentes le dejo un update con un codigo de ejemplo funcional. Saludos